# How do I select *unique* duplicates in MS Access SQL code from one table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, duplicates, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to use SQL to select uniquely duplicative service dates, all records of which are contained within a single table. Here's a sample starting table:

| GroupID | ServiceID | ServiceDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1/1/2010 |
| A | Y | 1/1/2010 |
| A | Z | 10/1/2010 |

I've figured out how to find 2 different records that have the same date and get them in one row, but I end up with a somewhat duplicated table, as it's comparing each record to all others:

| GroupID | ServiceID1 | ServiceDate1 | ServiceID2 | ServiceDate2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1/1/2010 | Y | 1/1/2010 |
| A | Y | 1/1/2010 | X | 1/1/2010 |

I don't want the last row, as it's essentially a duplicate of the first.

**Any ideas for how to get rid of that second row?**

Here's some replication code (and here's my SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/537d84)

```SQL
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  GroupID varchar(255),
  ServiceID varchar(255),
  ServiceDate Date
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (GroupID, ServiceID, ServiceDate)
VALUES ("A", "X", '2010-01-01'),
      ("A", "Y", '2010-01-01'),
      ("A", "Z", '2010-10-01');

SELECT DISTINCT 
  c1.ServiceID AS ServiceID1, c1.ServiceDate AS ServiceDate1, 
  c2.ServiceID AS ServiceID2, c2.ServiceDate AS ServiceDate2
FROM MyTable c1 INNER JOIN MyTable c2 
ON c1.GroupID = c2.GroupID 
WHERE (c1.ServiceID <> c2.ServiceID AND c1.ServiceDate = c2.ServiceDate);
```

NOTE: I thought I might be able to create A-B and B-A combined ID variables and then SELECT DISTINCT on them. Unfortunately, though, this is a slightly less capable version of SQL than MS Access (techincally, I'm writing it in VBA using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 connection string), so there is no CONCAT function, nor a CASE WHEN clause, among other deficiencies in syntax efficiency.

**Any ideas for how to get rid of that second row?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a `<>` condition, you'll always get duplicate results (x-y and y-x). Instead of using `<>`, you could arbitrarily decide that the smaller `ServiceId` should always by in `c1`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c1.ServiceID AS ServiceID1, c1.ServiceDate AS ServiceDate1, 
  c2.ServiceID AS ServiceID2, c2.ServiceDate AS ServiceDate2
FROM MyTable c1 INNER JOIN MyTable c2 
ON c1.GroupID = c2.GroupID 
WHERE (c1.ServiceID < c2.ServiceID AND c1.ServiceDate = c2.ServiceDate); 
-- Here ------------^
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I haven't had a chance to try yet but do you know if the "<" operator works on strings? I should have specified in the original post, but the IDs are character, not numeric.

Comment: @AlexSilverman `<` works for any type that can be ordered, including numbers (obviously), strings, and dates. The semantics of "a < b" mean "a comes before b". So, e.g, `'Alex' < 'Silverman'` will return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I have attached three images.

One shows the query design
the second shows the query output
the third shows the table data(without any query)

[image]

[image]

[image]